# SonarQube Process Start Issue

Tags: sonarqube

I am facing an issue while bringing up SonarQube 6.7.1 on Linux server as follows:

> [tele521
>   Dcip2):/dvp/lib/sft/cip2/install/sonarqube-6.7.1/sonarqube-6.7.1/logs]
>   uname -a Linux tele521 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 26
>   06:52:09 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"}

Error in sonar.log :

```
2018.02.23 10:00:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp `directory /dvp_llb_cip2_00_00/dvp/lib/sft/cip2/install/sonarqube-6.7.1/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp
2018.02.23 10:00:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /dvp_llb_cip2_00_00/dvp/lib/sft/cip2/install/sonarqube-6.7.1/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp
2018.02.23 10:00:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /0.0.0.0:9001
2018.02.23 10:00:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /0.0.0.0:9001
2018.02.23 10:00:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/dvp_llb_cip2_00_00/dvp/lib/sft/cip2/install/sonarqube-6.7.1/sonarqube-6.7.1/elasticsearch]: /dvp_llb_cip2_00_00/dvp/lib/sft/cip2/install/sonarqube-6.7.1/sonarqube-6.7.1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/dvp_llb_cip2_00_00/dvp/lib/sft/cip2/install/sonarqube-6.7.1/sonarqube-6.7.1/temp/conf/es
2018.02.23 10:00:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2018.02.23 10:00:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process [[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/dvp_llb_cip2_00_00/dvp/lib/sft/cip2/install/sonarqube-6.7.1/sonarqube-6.7.1/elasticsearch]: /dvp_llb_cip2_00_00/dvp/lib/sft/cip2/install/sonarqube-6.7.1/sonarqube-6.7.1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath
.conf=/dvp_llb_cip2_00_00/dvp/lib/sft/cip2/install/sonarqube-6.7.1/SonarQube    -6.7.1/temp/conf/es
 2018.02.23 10:00:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for  Elasticsearch to be up and running
 Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
  read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
  JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
   Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
  WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
  WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
  returned from WrapperListener.start()
  Send a packet STARTED :
  Startup runner thread stopped.
  read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
 JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
 read a packet STARTED :
JVM signalled that it was started.
 send a packet PING : ping
 Received a packet PING : ping
Send a packet PING : ok
 read a packet PING : ok
 Got ping response from JVM
 2018.02.23 10:00:26 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
 2018.02.23 10:00:26 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin    [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
 2018.02.23 10:00:26 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
 2018.02.23 10:00:26 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
 ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
 [1]: system call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your    configuration or disable system call filters at your own risk
  2018.02.23 10:00:28 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process   exited with exit value [es]: 78
  2018.02.23 10:00:28 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 78
  2018.02.23 10:00:28 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is   stopped
  2018.02.23 10:00:28 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped}
```

It is going for bootstrap checks however I have set the property as false in sonar.properties as

```
sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dbootstrap.system_call_filter=false
```

Also, I faced issues when i tried bringing up only elasticsearch process cause of bootstrap checks and updated elasticsearch.yml with property set as false post which the process came up.
But Sonar process still fails with the above exception.

Can you suggest something on this?
It is being hosted on tele521 server for me on port 9233.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Hello there,
PFB the es.log :

```
   2018.02.23 10:00:24 WARN  es[][o.e.b.JNANatives] unable tinstall         syscall   filter:
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: seccomp unavailable:   CONFIG_SECCOMP not compiled into kernel, CONFIG_SECCOMP and  CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER are needed
     at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.SystemCallFilter.linuxImpl (SystemCallFilter.java:364) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
     at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.SystemCallFilter.init(SystemCallFilter.java:639) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
     at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JNANatives.tryInstallSystemCallFilter(JNANatives.java:258) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
     at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.tryInstallSystemCallFilter(Natives.java:113) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:111) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    2018.02.23 10:00:24 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initializing ...
    2018.02.23 10:00:24 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data   paths, mounts [[/dvp_llb_cip2_00_00 (/dev/mapper/dvp_cip2_00_dg- dvp_llb_cip2_00_00_fs)]], net usable_space [4.2gb], net total_space [33.3gb],  spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
    2018.02.23 10:00:24 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [494.9mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
    2018.02.23 10:00:24 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [_su6ybLyRQmIJap_1joqWg]
    2018.02.23 10:00:24 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] version[5.6.3], pid[26129], build[1a2f265/2017-10-06T20:33:39.012Z], OS[Linux/2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_60/25.60-b23]
    2018.02.23 10:00:24 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Dbootstrap.system_call_filter=false, -Des.path.home=/dvp_llb_cip2_00_00/dvp/lib/sft/cip2/install/sonarqube-6.7.1/sonarqube-6.7.1/elasticsearch]
   2018.02.23 10:00:25 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
   2018.02.23 10:00:25 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [ingest-common]
   2018.02.23 10:00:25 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
   2018.02.23 10:00:25 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [percolator]
   2018.02.23 10:00:25 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [reindex]
   2018.02.23 10:00:25 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
   2018.02.23 10:00:25 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded
    2018.02.23 10:00:27 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery  type [zen]
  2018.02.23 10:00:27 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized
 2018.02.23 10:00:27 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ...
 2018.02.23 10:00:28 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address   {10.0.16.52:9001}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9001}
   2018.02.23 10:00:28 INFO  es[][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks] bound or   publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap   checks
   2018.02.23 10:00:28 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] node validation exception
  [1] bootstrap checks failed
  [1]: system call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your    configuration or disable system call filters at your own risk
   2018.02.23 10:00:28 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopping ...
   2018.02.23 10:00:28 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopped
   2018.02.23 10:00:28 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closing ...
   2018.02.23 10:00:28 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closed
```

Also, Sonar is being started with Dcip2 as user.
PFB the same :

```
  [tele521(Dcip2):/dvp/lib/sft/cip2/install/sonarqube-6.7.1/sonarqube-6.7.1/logs] less es.log
```

Comment: please provide the es.log -> can it be that you are starting sonar as root? elastic search will not start as root user!

Comment: I have edited the question with the latest es.log info.

Comment: @SimonSchrottner I have edited the question with the latest es.log info

Comment: yes i saw that, but i can not help you :D - it is just crucial to know why ES has stopped, but sadly i do not know the answer - but i am really sceptical about the UnSupportedException at the beginning :D

Comment: @SimonSchrottner Issue was with node configuration.